# The map Frame properties

Tags: arcmap, layouts, data-frame

I am working on Map Frame layout and would like to remove:
- the oval shape on the edge:  (to make it just 90 degrees)

[image]

- add  measurment 480 000   490000    and 4520000 450000 corresponding

[image]

I tried  Data  Frame Properties -->  not able to fix it.

Comment: can you elaborate on what is happening when you try the clip options in Data frame Properties and by any chance can you use ArcGIS pro coz they also have a feature like this named as reshape.

Comment: Did you use Data Frame Properties/Map Frame properties?